# PHP $_POST Variable does not get assigned in the command below it?

Tags: php, post

Thank you for your reply, Ok let me fix this question:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo $username;
```

This gives 'tjones', fine.

---

Now if I try this:

```
$filter = "(uid=$username)";
echo $filter;

(uid=)
```

How would one make `$filter` echo "`(uid=tjones)`" ?

Thanks again

Comment: You are saying that if you combine both your snippets in the same script it will print `tjones (uid=)`?

Comment: Yes drakes exactly.

Comment: Is this the full code? If $filter is inside a function then you may need `global $username` just above your second snippet. This may be a scope issue.

Comment: That's odd. What PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $filter = "(uid={$username})";
>
> echo $filter;

Comment: Thank you for commenting after reading all these comments I thought i was going mad, thank you for showing me the light!

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Although this answer has solved OP's question and is selected as accepted, But actually it's a low quality answer since there is not any description on why this error is happening and how does the answer is helping to solve the problem. IMO [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41412380/1908331) by @thecrazyprofessor is more reliable since he has explained the source of the error and how to solve it...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to use `{}`

Example:

```
$username = 'tjones';
$filter = "(uid={$username})";
echo $filter;
```

The `{}` tells PHP that the value inside isn't a part of the string and that secure that PHP know that it needs to look after the $username.

You may sometimes have seen people do `echo "Hello ".$username." Welcome back";` it's better use the `{}` like this `echo "Hello {$username} Welcome back";`

Answer (score 0):

If `tjones` is a string you should wrap it with quotes:

```
$username = "tjones";
echo $username;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. Check the [demo](https://eval.in/707215).

```
  <?php

$username = 'tjones';
$filter = "(uid=$username)";
echo $filter;
```

result:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
(uid=tjones)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. This is what I get:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant tjones - assumed 'tjones' in C:\php\test.php on line 3
(uid=tjones)
```

Same result in PHP 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0.

Your modified code also works if the value is assigned. Otherwise, you'll get *undefined index* notice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.` character to separate `string literals` and `$variables`.

by  ending the string with `"` (quotes) , then adding a `.` followed by the `$var`, another `.` and then start the `"` again if you wish to continue the string.

```
 <?php

   $username = 'tjones';
   $filter = "(uid=" . $username . ")";
   echo $filter;
  ?>
```